# Vue returning data objects from axios call to controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm using vue in laravel and trying to get a controller function that I'm hitting to return the data so that I can use it in the `data()` section of my vue template.

I know the controller function returns what I need, but I'm not so sure how I need to handle the return/response in the axios call in order to start placing the data into the data() function in vue

Blade/Vue template

```
import moment from 'moment'
export default {
    name: 'calendar',
    data () {
        return {
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'test',
                    allDay: true,
                    start: '2019-08-17',
                },
            ],
            config: {
                defaultView: 'month',
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    console.log(event)
                }
            },
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchTasks();
    },
    methods: {
      fetchTasks() {
        axios.get('/landing/tasks' )
            .then((response) => {
                // handle success
                this.assetOptions = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(function () {

        });
    }
}
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/landing/tasks', 'landingController@getTasks')
    ->name('landing/tasks');
```

Controller

```
public function getTasks()
{
    $getTask = Task::getTaskForLanding();

    $result = array();
    foreach($getTask as $id => $task){
        $result[$task->taskt_id][] = $task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that the Controller returns what you need, the only thing you are missing is declaration of `assetOptions`. To be able to assign `response.data` to `assetOptions` later on, you have to declare it in the `data` function first.

```
data() {
    return {
    ...
    assetOptions = []; // assuming you are expecting an array
    ...
    };
}
```

Once that is done, you are all set.